# Verify email changes not reflected on same session in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

In my Ionic 5 app with Firestore, I am trying to stop user from accessing the app before the email address is verified. This is done by a page when user is given a 'Continue' button to click after the email verification is done.

Following is code checking whether the email is verified by user.

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.emailVerified
```

This always returns `false` if I'm not closing the app and on the same session but it returns `true` if I restart the app.

I don't want to ask my users to restart the app as that is a bad user experience. Is there a way I can fix this or refresh the auth change so that the following `subscription` in the `app.component.ts` executes again.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user=>{
//retrigger this
})
```

Comment: did you try `await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reload();`

Comment: Hi @Aaron, this works. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reload();
```

before you try and access the account again